# Raw rgb frames to mpeg?

Tags: encoder, mpeg

Does anybody know of a simple dll that has like 3 main functions, i.e.

```
1. Start_recording_mpeg(<encoding>, <fps>, <file>, <etc>)
2. Encode_frame(<raw rgb data>)
3. Finish()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your RGB frames to YUV and then pipe them to ffmpeg as described in this [blog entry](http://kylecordes.com/2007/07/05/pipe-ffmpeg/).